# How to use Google Guice with encrypted properties?

Tags: java, spring, encryption, guice

There's a good guide hee [Guice and general application configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805874/guice-and-general-application-configuration) on using Google Guice to 'slurp' properties files into your system and then be able to inject them into your code.

But one thing that I was wondering is if you've got security around some of your properties, and they're encrypted with whatever mechanism, what's a good approach to decrypting and retrieving those entries? Is there even a standard approach?

I ask only because I know with prior Spring implementations I've seen, you can extend a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator through Jasypt or the like to handle the encryption/decryption of relevant properties entries. Is there something similar that people have worked with for Guice?

At present we're looking at building something ourselves, but I'm more than happy to be pointed at other approaches out there rather than reinvent the wheel.

Cheers,
Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach would be to implement a Guice `Module` which decrypts the properties and them available to the injector by the means of `bind` calls in it's `configure` method. Basically you'd just have to add your decryption part to the logic from the [question you already cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805874/guice-and-general-application-configuration).